# Suggested cutoff for high level VASP calculations

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, plane-waves

I am new at VASP, and apparently, cutoff convergence is not something like kpoint convergence. Is using `ENCUT=1.5xENMAX` can be justified? For RPA, GW and MP2 calculations, I cannot use larger values.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, the largest you would need for convergence, is `ENCUT = 1.3 * ENMAX`. This is the same as specifying as the `PREC = ACCURATE`. Going beyond these typically only changes the energy of the system of very few meV.

Answer (score 3):

I would go farther and ask, why is cutoff convergence unlike kpoint convergence?  You can very easily do a convergence study based on energy cutoffs.  Infact, this is often how `ENMAX` is determined in a code.

Here is an example from the [GPAW documentation](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/setups/Ni.html) of the convergence of the Ni PAW potential.  As you can see, the error drops as the energy cutoff increases, you should determine what an acceptable error for your work.

[image: https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/setups/Ni.html]

You can also look at the convergence of things such as band structures relative to `ENCUT`.  In general though, as long as the `ENCUT` is consistent, things should at least be comparable.